Why the second C in "recyceln" is pronounced [k] instead of [ts]?
In German, the letter C is usually pronounced [ts] before E, e.g. "Cent".
It seems to me "risaikeln" would make more sense than "recyceln" in German orthography.
If the intent was copying the English word, like it's done in "Sandwich", why not write "recyclen" (given that German prefers verbs with an N at the end)?

Your headline seems to contradict the textual statement and I have some problems with the generality of the first sentence.

There are languages that strictly modify loanwords according to their spelling and grammar rules, but in German we often have a mixture of keeping English spelling and German endings or grammar rules. "recyclen" might get pronounced as "risaiklen". The pronunciation of a consonant might depend on the vowel before or after it. See "Cafe" for the pronunciation as [k].

Often, we Germans keep loanwords in their original spelling but also create native german words as a formal alternative (Recycling is also Kreislaufwirtschaft, recyceln is also wiederverwerten, a "Computer" is also known as a "Rechner"). "risaikeln" would strike us as more of a japanese loanword.

Verbs ending in -eln also have an -n at the end.

Having said that, I would put this question as "why is the K sound spelled with a C?" -- as a native English speaker I'd sooner use recyckeln or recykeln, because ‹c› is generally pronounced /s/ before ‹e›, but obviously it's for the native German speakers to decide how to spell things in German.

It is obvious that the German pronunciation of the two letters "c" in "recyceln"  was adopted from the English pronunciation of "recycle". Therefore your question is really about spelling: Why  "recyceln" instead of  "recyclen"?
The German spelling reflects the English pronunciation "risaikel". It transforms "recycle" to "recycel" and appends an "n" (which is the standard ending of German verbs). Indeed the German spelling is a mixture of English spelling and English pronunciation.

Both, DWDS and de.wiktionary.org also mention the variation "recyclen", which IMHO renders the pronounciation of the second "c" more intuitive.

We need to clarify a few things up front, because several of your assumptions are wrong:

given that German prefers verbs with an N at the end

No, German does not "prefer" verbs with a suffix "-n", but there are in fact only three endings a German verb can have (in infinitive form):

-en (gehen, stehen, ... most verbs)
-ern (wandern, rudern, ... many derived from nouns e.g. "Ärger"->"ärgern")
-eln (sticheln, schmeicheln, ... many derived from nouns, e.g. "Kabel"->"kabeln")

Note that "-ern" and "-eln" are the result of removed "-e-" between l/r and "-n". So, we could, brushing over that detail, say that "-en" is the only ending a verb can have in infinitive.

would make more sense than "recyceln"

No, not at all. For the same reason it is "googeln" and not "googlen", because in German "-le-" cannot be pronounced "el" (or, rather, "schwa-l") like in English. The way this word was "germanized" was: take "recyc" and add a verb ending that mostly resembles the way the english word sounds. This was "-eln" as the closest match.

It seems to me "risaikeln" would make more sense

No, not at all. We have to talk about a language trait which made German but indo-european languages in general so immensely successful: the ability to assimilate foreign words (and the underlying concepts they represent) on the fly. The moment I use any foreign word it becomes a German word - and there is no going back:

Ich habe im Büro die Files für den Roboter upgedatet.

"Büro" is french, "Files" and "update" is English and "Roboter" is Russian (actually, as I was told, first used in a Czech novel; I still think that "Roboter" is derived from the Russian - Slav? - word "raboti", "to work"), but the whole sentence is perfect German. And even "update" is used as a "non-separable composite verb" and given a perfect tense marker to create a past participle, along with German perfect tense ending: "up-ge-datet" instead of "geupdated" even though the English past participle would be "updated".
For a similar reason the plural for "Espresso" is not "Espressi" but "Espressos". First off, an "Espresso" is not a certain making of coffee ("made fast"), but a coffee you drink fast ("auf die Schnelle"). And second, in Italy (OK, in the part of Naples where I ordered "due espressi" and earned a blank stare, until my friend said, grinning, "due caffe") you don't order "due espressi" either, you order "due caffe". But, third and most important here, when "Espresso" is used in a German sentence it is already a German word and therefore German declination rules apply if not especially motivated forms apply:

singular "die Sphinx", plural: "die Sphingen"

This is because "Sphinx" is a greek word and the Greek plural would be built that way, but in fact this is the invention of people able to speek Greek (and being proud of it) at a time were only a few select intellectuals at universities were able to do so. This is just them parading around their learned knowledge to impress upon the heathens. Equally correct:

singular "die Sphinx", plural: "die Sphinxe(n)"

So, let us come back to "recyceln": the word comes from Greek "kyklos", which means "circle". Actually the words "circle" and "cycle" and also the German "Zirkel" and "Zyklus" is derived from it ("circle" and the like via the Latin "circulus/circus", which also comes from "kyklos"). You see that the two "c" letters are in fact eroded "k"-sounds and while English made the first to an "s" and the second to "k" German made the first to "ts" (z). There is even a "genuine" German word, "rezyklieren", which means the same as "recyceln", but in a less modern, sexy way.

Regardless of whether the pronunciation is adopted from English, it's pretty inevitable to have a /k/ sound in it, seeing as "Zyklus", "zyklisch" etc. are also established German words. Both the English and German versions come via Latin from ancient Greek κύκλος, which actually has two /k/ sounds.
Better questions to ask are therefore the following:
1. Why is it not pronounced /rekükeln/?
It happened in the evolution of Latin from classical ("c" always pronounced /k/) to medieval/ecclestial that many "c" words got the /ts/ pronounciation. In English this further developed into /s/. A well-known example is

Cæsar in classical Latin pronounced /kä:sa/
Zäsar / Cäsar in modern German pronounced /tsä:sa/
Cesar in modern English pronounced /si:sar/

In "recyceln", the first "c" is pronounced in the Englisch style. A variant that used the German style is "rezirkulieren" /re:tsirkuliren/, uncommonly also "rezyklieren" /re:tsükliren/
This transformation does not apply to the "cl" cluster though, I reckon because /tsl/ is just awkward to pronounce.
2. Why is it not written "riseikeln"?
Because German does not usually adapt loanwords from English to exactly follow German orthography ("Computer", "T-shirt", "Gaffatape"...), they are only changed enough to be compatible with the available letters and the grammar. Some other languages nativise spelling more aggressively: the Norwegian word for bicycle is adapted from the English one but written "sykkel".

Actually tsl is not especially awkward to pronounce for German tongues, it occurs e. g. in kitzlig and plötzlich.

@guidot the point is not about what's (not) awkward in German but what would have been awkward in Latin. The German "recyceln" doesn't have "cl" anyway, so it wouldn't apply. Also, German /tsl/ actually tends to come out more like /tsel/, "kitzelig".
